# What is the boundary of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the space $X = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$ with the standard Euclidean topology, and the subset $A = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \subset X$. I am trying to determine the ***boundary of A.***

Following the definition, I am running into some problems, so let me state the definition below:

> Given a topological space $(X, \tau), A \subset X$, the ***boundary*** of $A$ is $\partial A := \bar{A} \cap (\overline{X \setminus A})$ where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of A.

Okay, so now I'll display my work in finding the boundary of $A=\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ in the topological space $X =\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q} $ using this definition:

> So, $\bar{A} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$. This makes sense. Then plugging this into the definition above, $\partial A := \bar{A} \cap (\overline{X \setminus A}) =\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q} \cap( \overline{(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}) \setminus (\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}))} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q} \cap (\overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \times \emptyset}) = \mathbb{R} \times \emptyset$.

Okay, as far as I'm aware, there is nothing wrong with this, but obviously there is, because in fact $\partial A = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$. This also seems to make some sort of intuitive sense, because the interior of $A$ is empty and the closure of $A$ is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$. Obviously this true answer and the answer I obtained from the definition are not the same.

Why is this? Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $$(\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q)\setminus(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\times\mathbb Q,$$ the reason being that if $x\notin\mathbb Q,$ then $(x,y)\notin(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)$ whatever $y$ is.
Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:** For $(x,y)\in(\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q),$ by definition, $(x,y)\in(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)\iff x\in\mathbb Q\text{ and }y\in\mathbb Q.$ So $(x,y)\notin(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)\iff x\notin\mathbb Q\text{ or }y\notin\mathbb Q,$ but the latter is clearly impossible, and hence the conclusion.

Comment: I see. Would you be able to explain this a bit more at all? not 100% on this...

Comment: I edited; tell me if more is needed. BTW, I have to sleep now. :)

Comment: Cheers. Got it now... sleep well :)

Answer (score 4):

Spoted a mistake.

It should be

$$(\mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{Q} ) \backslash (\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q})=(\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}) \times \mathbb{Q}$$